# Count amount of ID

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have the following output from a MySQL query:

```
count, cat1id, cat1name, cat2id, cat2name, cat3id, cat3name
10, NULL, NULL, 1000, Main Category, 1001, Sub Category 1
5, 1000, Main Category, 1001, Sub Category 1, 1002, Sub Category 2
50, NULL, NULL, 1000, Main Category, 1003, Another Category
```

What I would like to see is the following output (pre formatted text)

```
Main Category (65)
+ Sub Category 1 (10)
++ Sub Category 2 (5)
+ Another Category (50)
```

I'm no programming guru and having a hard time to understand how I can count the amount of occurrences of a specific ID when this ID is mentioned in different columns. I've tried using arrays, but find them complex in this situation. I was thinking of a bunch of IF's or a CASE, which would work in this example, but the database contains over 2000 categories.

Can anyone point my in the right direction or show me a snippet how to output the requested data based on the MySQL query?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe a count(*) will do, i'm unsure about this. Some people here will help but they probably need to know the Mysql Query

Comment: which column of your is specifying the primary key here???

Comment: What you see there is already the output of doing a count. What happens is that in a separate table there's a column called 'CategoryID'. I did a count of that. Maybe the question is not clear enough: what I wish to establish is to get the results (output) as mentioned from the results as shown. This has to be done with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Then try this

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT(YourID) FROM YourTbale";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
      $subQ="Select * from YourTbale" where YourID = $row[0];
        echo "$row[0]( mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con,$subQ)) )"; //$con carries connection string
    }

    $result->close();
}
```